# Can you combine multiple lists with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say I have two lists:

```
var list1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
var list2 = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

Is it possible to write a LINQ statement that will generate the following list:

```
var result = new []{ 
    new {i = 1, s = "a"},
    new {i = 1, s = "b"},
    new {i = 1, s = "c"},
    new {i = 2, s = "a"},
    new {i = 2, s = "b"},
    new {i = 2, s = "c"},
    new {i = 3, s = "a"},
    new {i = 3, s = "b"},
    new {i = 3, s = "c"}
};
```

?

Edit: I forgot to mention I didn't want it in query syntax. Anyway, based on preetsangha's answer I've got the following:

```
var result = list1.SelectMany(i =>  list2.Select(s => new {i = i, s = s}));
```

Comment: What's wrong with query syntax?

Comment: Yes, weird that you would select Jon's reply as the answer when preetsangha got in first and had another version of the same code (with due respect to Jon).

Comment: If I could pick both I would. As for not liking query syntax, I just don't like it. It feels wrong as it doesn't fit in with C# and not all the new stuff in LINQ is available in query syntax, like ToList() etc.

Comment: you can do (from l1 in list1
             from l2 in list2       
             select new { i = l1, s = l2}).ToList();

Answer (score 21, accepted):

preetsangha's answer is entirely correct, but if you don't want a query expression then it's:

```
var result = list1.SelectMany(l1 => list2, (l1, l2) => new { i = l1, s = l2} );
```

(That's what the compiler compiles the query expression into - they're identical.)

Answer (score 43):

```
var result = from l1 in list1
             from l2 in list2       
             select new { i = l1, s = l2};
```